# Django FIlter: Filtering object hidden in multi layered model structure

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I have a following django model relationship:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    pass 
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    project=ForeignKey(Project) 
class Concept(models.Model):
    vehicle=ManyToManyField(Vehicle) 
class Analysis(models.Model):
    concept=ForeignKey(Concept)
```

I want to sort out all Analyses objects which are connected to a Project with a known id.
Concept can be for more than one vehicle but all the vehicles within a concept will be limited to only one Project.
Or should i justadd to all following  models a foreignkey with a project field?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the name of te `ForeignKey`s and `ManyToManyField`s.

Comment: please [edit] the question.

Comment: now should be understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
Analysis.objects.filter(concept__vehicle__project_id=project_id)
```

It is possible that a `Concept` has many `Vehicle`s that point to the same `Project`, and in that case the `Analysis` will be duplicated. You can use [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to prevent this:

```
Analysis.objects.filter(concept__vehicle__project_id=project_id).distinct()
```

---

> **Note**: Since a `ManyToManyField` refers to a *collection* of elements,
> `ManyToManyField`s are normally given a *plural* name. You thus might want
> to consider renaming <s>`vehicle`</s> to `vehicles`.